# Recognize modifiers keys in EFI

Tags: uefi

when you press a modifier key in macOS,Windows or Linux,... The On-screen Keyboard shows which modifiers are being pressed, even when you don't press a normal key. So how to do the same thing in EFI(EDKII).
Thanks.

Comment: See the SetState and ReadKeyStrokeEx functions in EFI_SIMPLE_TEXT_INPUT_EX_PROTOCOL.

Comment: What I meant is how to recognize the modifier key being pressed without another key just like grub.